# How do I use print! with Rocket when compiling for release?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I've got some route handlers with `print!()` statements in it. They work just fine when I compile my app for debug. However, when compiling for release, Rocket appears to be "muting" all the print statements (as well as logging functions from `log` crate). Why is it doing so? How do I force it to print things then building for release? I suspect it might be connected to log level, which is automatically set to critical when compiling for release, however, I'm not quite sure what level do `print!` statements have and how to change the logging level.

Comment: I don't remember tracing can capture `print` statement. Can you provide an example of what you get ?

Comment: You are specifically mentioning `print!()`, which does not [`flush()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush) `stdout` after writing to it, so its output usually appears to be muted. As you mention, `rocket` sets the [default log level](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/configuration/#overview) to `normal` in debug builds, which will produce more/any logs, which in turn cause a `flush()` and therefore your `print()`-output to be flushed as well. Use `println!()` or manually `flush()`.

Comment: @user2722968 that worked, thanks! Would you like to add this as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: @keddad added the answer so this can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifically mentioning `print!()`, which does not [`flush()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush) `stdout` after writing to it, so its output usually appears to be muted.

As you mention, `rocket` sets the default log-level to `normal` in debug builds, which will produce more/any logs, which in turn cause a `flush()` and therefore your `print!()`-output to be flushed as well.

Use [`println!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.println.html) or manually [`flush()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush) .

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add a quick reference for How to `flush` after `print`

In Rust, the `print!` macro is buffered by default, which means that the output may not be immediately visible. To flush the output buffer and ensure that your `print!` statements are immediately visible, you can use the `std::io::stdout()` function and call its `flush()` method.

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    print!("Hello, world!");
    io::stdout().flush().unwrap(); // flushes the output buffer
}
```